# silverlight/wpf webbrowser encoding

Tags: c#, silverlight, encoding, browser

i was looking for a long time to get a solution for polish charset in wpf webbrowser. After few hours of playing i made a solution, maybe someone else will need it also so i share.

```
private string EncodeUnicode(string strText)
    {
        string txtUnicode = "";
        foreach (char value in strText)
        {
            txtUnicode += Regex.Replace(Convert.ToString(value), "[ęóąśłżźćńĘÓĄŚŁŻŹŃ]", "&#" + (int.Parse(string.Format("{0:x4}", (int)value), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString());
        }
        return txtUnicode;
    }
```

Ofcourse you can replace ęóąśłżźćńĘÓĄŚŁŻŹŃ with your pattern.
And than just use

```
WebBrowser.NavigateToString(EncodeUnicode(Content));
```

If someone got better solution plz share it also.

Comment: "get a solution for polish charset" what was the problem?  Why can't you just include the characters as they are, why to do they need escaping?

Comment: well, when i use WPF webbrowser then all polish chars are not showing, even if the HTML inside got proper charset in metatag. Its good in WINFORMS webbrowser but not silverlight/wpf.

Comment: I couldn't find better solution, but fortunately Your solution works pretty good for me, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'>
```

within `<head></head>` tag of your html string.

I had the same problem, your solution worked for me, and this worked too.